# How to kill a System Extension or Network Extension?

Tags: swift, macos, kill, networkextension, macos-system-extension

So I'm building a macOS app with a Network Extension in Swift. After some tests, the extension remains as a process in the system. I can stop and also I can kill the app but I cannot stop, kill or unload the Network Extension. The Network Extension emerges again and again.

I restarted macOS but the Network Extension is still there as a process. How can I completely remove it from the System?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to remove it by one of the following 2 methods:

- Delete the host application from `/Applications` using the Finder. This should prompt you that it will remove any associated system extensions. (May not work if you've disabled the requirement for host apps residing in `/Applications` on your system. This is done [using the `systemextensionsctl developer on` terminal command](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/debugging_and_testing_system_extensions?language=objc#3557204))
- Submit an extension deactivation request created using the [`+deactivationRequestForExtension:queue:` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemextensions/ossystemextensionrequest/3295273-deactivationrequestforextension) on `OSSystemExtensionRequest`. This is the complement of the activation request you used to install the extension in the first place.

Comment: You may also use 'systemextensionsctl uninstall [teamid] [bundleid]' in terminal for the first point. Use 'systemextensionsctl list' to view current enabled system extensions.

Comment: You may need to run `csrutil disable` in Recovery mode terminal before you can uninstall with `systemextensionsctl uninstall`. Don't forget to turn on SIP (System Integrity Protection) again with `csrutil enable`.

Comment: @rmalviya Uninstalling and rebooting without disabling SIP should also work, but the mechanism has certainly been buggy in some OS versions. 10.15.6 seems reliable though. In the worst case, you can disable SIP, delete the extension from `/Library/SystemExtensions/<UUID>`, edit the file `/Library/SystemExtensions/db.plist` to remove the extension from there too, then reboot, and then re-enable SIP.

Comment: In macOS Catalina v10.15.6, `systemextensionsctl` produces following output:

`At this time, this tool cannot be used if System Integrity Protection is enabled.
This limitation will be removed in the near future.
Please remember to re-enable System Integrity Protection!`

Comment: Removing the install folder from `/Applications` will not remove the system extension on Monterey. I banged my head against the wall over this bc my test extension would not update between test iterations. In order to replace it the version number has to be higher, and as @rmalviya said...`systemextensionsctl` will not work unless you disable SIP

Comment: @pmdj. Hi, I was wondering if there's a way to catch the deactivation request  `+deactivationRequestForExtension:queue:` in the extension side and decide whether to approve/discard the operation. Perhaps there's a way to prevent the deactivation in some circumstances from the extension side? thanks !

Comment: @Zohar81 I'm not aware of any such facility. You may be able achieve it via an Endpoint Security system extension, but I don't have much practical experience with those.